# Customizing Mezzanine (use different thems)

Tags: python, django, themes, mezzanine

I am working on a **multisite project** and right now there is only one theme I am using for both sites , So is there any way that **I can use different theme for each site** and if I change the one theme it doesn't affect the other one.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the HOST_THEMES setting:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html#host-themes

Comment: Thanks Steve for your help! Docs have been moved to: 
https://mezzanine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#host-themes